# NetSuite: Why our Sales Order created through webstore comes with Payment Event = Pending

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitecommerce

In NetSuite, we are trying to create a Sales Order through webstore but when the Sales Order gets created, in Billing subtab > Payments Events, **the Payments Events record is in status/result="Pending"** and on the top of Sales Order record I cannot see "Fulfill", "Next Bill", "Bill Remaining" etc. buttons instead there is button **"Override Pending Payment"**. When "Override Pending Payment" button is clicked, Payment Event status/result becomes "Accept". Can anyone please mention possible reasons for why Payment Event record goes into status="Pending"? How we can bypass "Pending" status and go directly in "Accept" status of Payment Event? Many Thanks

Also, I was able to find help online about Managing Payment Holds. When Payment Event goes into status="Payment Hold". NetSuite has page to handle this status: Transaction > Sales > Managing Payment Holds and also on user role we can add permission, Transactions > Override Payment Holds. But for status="Pending" there is no page and no Override permission. Is "Pending" status new in NetSuite?

Answer (score 1):

Is the webstore handling the credit card payment? If so, you probably need to set 'CCapproved' to True... That tells NetSuite that the payment processing was handled eternal to NetSuite. (You may also want to transmit the P/N number so you can handle refunds...)